# Kindle - How to add downloaded book to kid's account?

Tags: kindle

The device is Kindle Basic 10th Gen 2019. I have created a child account in Settings/Parental Controls/Amazon Kids and I am trying to add a downloaded book to it. However, the Kindle shows this message even though there are some downloaded books in Kindle:

> You currently do not own any books. If you purchase books later, you
> can share them with your children via parents.amazon.com

Does this mean that only books from the Kindle Store can be added to a child's account? How can I add downloaded books to the child's account?